# What is difference between a PWA in edge the browser versus installed regarding push notifications?

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge

Problem: My PWA application shows push notifications when in Edge browser. But when the application is installed using Edge the push notifications are not longer shown. This is on desktop both Windows 10 and Windows 11 there is no problem with Edge on Android. There is also no problem with Chrome on desktop.

I have used the browser debug options to track where things go wrong. However no error occurs. The push notification is registered as "Push event dispatch" and "Push completed" under Push Messaging. Under Notifications the notification is registered as displayed.

To explore the problem further tested the Push notifications demo from Microsoft Edge (webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net). This application shows the push notification when the application is installed with Edge. Then I used the code from the demo in my own application. And again there are no notifications shown when the application is installed. While the debugger indicates that the push notification is received and displayed.

There seems to be an difference between permissions for push notifications between when Edge receives a push notifications for a website and when the PWA is installed. But when checking the permissions, they are based on the url which is obviously the same whether installed or not.

What are other options to investigate on what the problem is?
Are there any errors or warnings Lighthouse that might be ignored when it is a website and not when the pwa is installed?

Comment: By "when the application is installed using Edge", how did you install this app? What's the difference between this app and your PWA app?

Comment: PWA means progressive web application. 
Installing means in Edge under settings > apps you will find the name of the app with the question to install. The web application also catches the beforeinstallprompt trigger to have an install button in the application. 
There is no difference between (in code) between when the web application is used in the browser or when it is installed.

Comment: Alright. So according to your description in the question, there's no notification when it is installed via Edge but it shows notifications in your own app. But using the official demo, the situation is completely opposite. Am I misunderstanding something? We can troubleshoot this issue starting from the official demo.

Comment: >So according to your description in the question, there's no notification when it is installed via Edge but it shows notifications in your own app.
Yes 
>But using the official demo, the situation is completely opposite. 
No The official demo works. Both in the browser as well as installed. But using the service worker code of the official demo in my website/application it works in the browser but not when installed using Edge. Which together with no error being raised let me to believe it is not something related to the code in the service worker but something else.

Comment: Got it. Just a thought: you can try managing privacy settings again in your PWA. More action (···) --> Privacy --> Manage privacy settings --> Notifications --> Ask (default). This will re-grant a notification permission. See if this helps.